# import error: <module 'main' from 'C:\Users\Anjali\Desktop\malbee-phish\main.py'> has no attribute app

Tags: python, google-app-engine

i converted my code from python 2.5 to 2.7 following the tutorials available but I'm encountering many errors as can be seen in this log file that was generated when i run the code. Please help me resolve these errors

```
 File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 269,    in _LoadHandler
      raise ImportError('%s has no attribute %s' % (handler, name))
ImportError: <module 'main' from 'C:\Users\Anjali\Desktop\malbee-phish\main.py'> has no attribute app
BadStatusLine("''",)
BadStatusLine("''",)
```

Comment: You need to include you app.yaml (at least the definition of your handler) and your main.py.

We will see a few things you have missed.  The definition in your app.yaml is probably referring to main.app  .  With the recommended handler for 2.7 you are defining handler in a python module and not just specifying the python script with a __main__ in it.  

So on the info provided it looks like you haven't changed you handler definition.  You can still use the old cgi model, but it still affects your handler definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you set `threadsafe: true`. This only works if your application uses WSGI. Transition your application to use WSGI ([preferred](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/diff27#Preferred_Interface)) or set `threadsafe: false`.

You may also have to [change your application to use `webapp2`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/migrate27#webapp2).